# connect to TFS with TortoiseGit or msysgit?

Tags: tfs, tortoisegit

I made a new blank TFS git project and tried to clone it in a new folder on my desktop using TortoiseGit and msysgit.  It always fails saying 'Authentication failed'.
I typed:

"git clone https://saratoga.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Git%20Test."

When prompted for my username I entered my Windows account email address (e.g. bob@example.org).

It then asked for my password for

"https://test@saratoga.visualstudio.com"

i entered the password. However, I am unable to connect to the tfs service, message appear that authentication failed in tortoise git.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Alternative Authentication Credentials** in TFS provides a solution, use the following instructions:

1. Click on your name in the upper right of screen.
2. Click on My Profile.
3. Click on the Credentials tab.
4. Setup an alternate username that doesn't include the @ character.

Now when you connect to the remote repo via TortoiseGit, you can use the alternate credentials and those new credentials should work.

Comment: What is the correct term for Microsoft's online TFS service?  Very confusing terminology.

Comment: >What is the correct term for Microsoft's online TFS service? Very confusing terminology? -- Visual Studio Online

Comment: @DenisEfimov It's Visual Studio Team Services or VSTS.